# Find the inverse of $A+uB+vC+uvD+u^2E+v^2F$ where $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Given scalars  $u,v$ s.t. $0<u,v<1$, we seek the properties of the matrix defined by

$$P=A+uB+vC+uvD+u^2E+v^2F$$

A is symmetric and positive definite. $B,C,D,E,F$ are symmetric, but might not be positive definite. 
The matrices are of arbitrary size.

What can we say about $P$?
If we assume all matrix inverses exist, what can you say about $P$?
What other assumptions reveal information about $P$?

Update: We know that we can rewrite $P$:

$$ P = (I,uI,vI)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}A&B/2&C/2 \\ B/2&  E & D/2 \\ C/2&D/2&F \\ \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}I \\ uI\\vI \end{array}\right)$$

Identities that might be relevant
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_inverse_theorem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

This is a problem I ran into while trying to prove something about my research. Any ideas would help!

Comment: I would suggest analyzing the case of $1 \times 1$ matrices first, in which the properties of bilinear forms might prove useful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections

Comment: The conic sections seem helpful, I'm trying to figure out how that extends to larger matrices

Comment: I got it: if you use $(u I,v I, I)T$ as the homogeneous coordinate vector,  I think we get the desired result